# How to remove random rows of zero quantities of a multiple array in C#?

Tags: c#

How to remove random rows of zero quantities (all in string types) of a multiple array in C#?  Coded please! :))

Ex: index Code,Color, Quantities, RetailPrice, WholeSalePrice

```
0 1002, red, 0, 150, 100
1 1003, blue, 0, 160, 100
2 1004, yellow, 3, 180, 130
3 1004, green, 6, 140, 103
4 1008, pink, 8, 200, 140
5 1008, black, 0, 200, 140
6 1008, white, 0, 200, 140
7 1008, blue, 0, 200, 140
8 1008, purple, 4, 200, 140
9 1009, light blue, 2, 280, 210
10 1000, stripe, 4, 170, 115
11 1003, white, 2, 230, 175
12  1009, white, 2, 230, 175
13  1001, white, 0, 230, 175
14  1000, black, 0, 230, 175
```

Result:
    index Code,Color, Quantities, RetailPrice, WholeSalePrice

```
1 1004, yellow, 3, 180, 130
2 1004, green, 6, 140, 103
3 1008, pink, 8, 200, 140
4 1008, purple, 4, 200, 140
5 1009, light blue, 2, 280, 210
6 1000, stripe, 4, 170, 115
7 1003, white, 2, 230, 175
8 1009, white, 2, 230, 175
```

Any one can help please?

Comment: What have _you_ tried?

Comment: Do you need rows which CONTAIN zeroes to be removed entirely, or simply the zeroes?  It would appear you need the whole row terminated?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something as:

1. Create a list to store the remaining arrays.
2. Iterate over your array

   foreach (item in array)
   {
       if ( item[2] != "0" )
           remaining.Add(item);
   }
3. return the the list (as array if you want)

   return remaining.ToArray();

Comment: I agree with the array idea, and testing foreach, but what if a String.Split() was used on a comma, storing each split to an array, and testing the array for zeroes?

Comment: I think it should work also, just drop my 2 cents from my phone. Plus, maybe the comas on the OP refer to the array items and not to actual commas.

Answer (score 0):

Techniques that might come in handy:

- index your array, e.g. `var quantity = array[2]`
- filter your list

  - linq, anyone?
  - for loop, copy to a new `List<string[]>`
  - `yield result` generator

Answer (score 0):

You can't really "remove" items from an array (arrays have a fixed size).

You can, however, create an empty `List<string[]>`, iterate over your array and only add an item to the list if its count isn't `0`.

There are many ways to do this. You could do it with a `for`-/`foreach`-loop, or by using [Linq (click here for an introduction)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397906.aspx). Using `.ToArray()` at the end of a Linq query (or on a `List`) gives you an array.

I won't post any code though :P